# ADB PUSH fails when the file name includes non-ASCII

Tags: android, cmd, adb

I wrote a Batch command to push file into the WSA virtual machine.

```
chcp 65001
adb kill-server
adb connect localhost:58526
for %%i in (%*) do (
 set val=%%i
 adb -s localhost:58526 push %%i /sdcard/download/
)
pause
```

And when I try to push a file in the name of which non-ASCII characters included, it fails like this:

```
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\第4天教育制度、学生与
教师.pdf' to '/sdcard/download/.': remote couldn't create file: Is a directory
C:\Users\username\Desktop\第4天教�.... 63.7 MB/s (309993 bytes in 0.005s)
```

I tried to push files with ASCII-only names, and it worked just fine.
I appreciate your help if I could push non-ASCII files without modifying the name.

Answer (score 0):

It is because adb.exe use  mingw toolchains. t is mingw toolchains' problem.
the chinese name  is truncated in `basename()` function in mingw-w64-crt/misc/basename.c.
see  https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/227/
also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143232373

Comment: I have fixed the bug.see my release.https://github.com/fjh1997/gdb-for-windows-nonascii